# Current project path in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

How to get root path of current working project in Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.Forms project? Forms project is PCL, hence I am trying out in Xamarin.Android project. Tried following things:

```
string rootPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath;
string rootPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath;
string rootPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
string rootPath = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
string rootPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

Everything is returning null. I want to dynamically create file in particular folder, for that I need root path of my project. How to get it?

Comment: The current path of the project in the IDE or the path of the app on the device?

Comment: @matthewrdev, Project path in the IDE

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this at runtime; your best approach is to bake the project path into a constant string using a t4 script.